# How to fix this Dockerfile for ASP.NET Core with React template?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I have the ff. dockerfile for my aspnet core 2.1 with react template webapp. My aspnet core sdk is 2.1.301. But the build always fail. The error message is located below

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1.1-aspnetcore-runtime-alpine3.7 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1.301-sdk-alpine3.7 AS build

# set up node
ENV NODE_VERSION 10.5.0
ENV NODE_DOWNLOAD_SHA 5d77d2c68c06404028f063dca0947315570ff5e52e46f67f93ef9f6cdcb1b4a8
RUN curl -SL "https://nodejs.org/dist/v${NODE_VERSION}/node-v${NODE_VERSION}-linux-x64.tar.gz" --output nodejs.tar.gz \
&& echo "$NODE_DOWNLOAD_SHA nodejs.tar.gz" | sha256sum -c - \
&& tar -xzf "nodejs.tar.gz" -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 \
&& rm nodejs.tar.gz \
&& ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/nodejs

WORKDIR /src
COPY webapp.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore webapp.csproj
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build webapp.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish webapp.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "webapp.dll"]
```

Here's the logs

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  69.63MB
Step 1/17 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1.1-aspnetcore-runtime-alpine3.7 AS base
 ---> a50663099cc8
Step 2/17 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> eb9a35d94f33
Step 3/17 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1.301-sdk-alpine3.7 AS build
 ---> d5accd0a6f97
Step 4/17 : ENV NODE_VERSION 10.5.0
 ---> Running in e7797f27733e
Removing intermediate container e7797f27733e
 ---> c1b611e0b1eb
Step 5/17 : ENV NODE_DOWNLOAD_SHA 
5d77d2c68c06404028f063dca0947315570ff5e52e46f67f93ef9f6cdcb1b4a8
 ---> Running in 07ee74558e7a
Removing intermediate container 07ee74558e7a
 ---> 3d0a2d6f2a9f
Step 6/17 : RUN curl -SL "https://nodejs.org/dist/v${NODE_VERSION}/node-v${NODE_VERSION}-linux-x64.tar.gz" --output nodejs.tar.gz     && echo "$NODE_DOWNLOAD_SHA nodejs.tar.gz" | sha256sum -c -     && tar -xzf "nodejs.tar.gz" -C /usr/local --strip-components=1     && rm nodejs.tar.gz     && ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/nodejs
 ---> Running in c72c1e9a3593
/bin/sh: curl: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c curl -SL "https://nodejs.org/dist/v${NODE_VERSION}/node-v${NODE_VERSION}-linux-x64.tar.gz" --output nodejs.tar.gz     && echo "$NODE_DOWNLOAD_SHA nodejs.tar.gz" | sha256sum -c -     && tar -xzf "nodejs.tar.gz" -C /usr/local --strip-components=1     && rm nodejs.tar.gz     && ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/nodejs' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

I based the Dockerfile above from the output of Docker for Visual Studio then removed the docker compose project and moved the Dockerfile from the parent folder (alongside the .sln) to inside the project itself (alongside the .csproj)

I believe the template includes the CRA build in the Startup.cs so it needs Node (npm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh sorry. I got this working now, I just had to use microsoft/dotnet:2.1.301-sdk instead of the Alpine one for the build. Then it ran okay